# Potentially missing 10GB space on C drive.

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, disk-space

I'm using windows 8.1 on my laptop and I's using a 512GB SSD drive as the system drive (C drive).

I have recently found out that my C drive is potentially missing almost 10GB space. Please see the pictures.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvtMQ.jpg) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2HWO.jpg) One picture being the screen shot of the virtual memory window, the other one is the game install notification in Steam. Both of them suggested that there are more than 395GB free space on my C drive, while the "(C:) Properties" shows that there are only 386GB. 
I have done a lot of research for this and tried the following methods but it still doesn't work. Please help!!

1. I ran a virus scan for the whole C drive using Mcafee, no virus detected.
2. Right click C drive--Properties--Disk Clean-up--Clean up system files.
3. I went to "This PC--Properties--Advanced system settings--System Protection", deleted the restore points for C drive.
4. I also optimised the C drive using "Optimise Drives ".

And now I have truely run out of resorts. 
This problem doesn't really interfere any daily usage, but it is really really annoying because I don't know what's causing it and whether it will cause any troubles in the future.

Comment: You're using an SSD... I would consider whether you need hibernation features enabled.  If you don't plan to use hibernate (I never do on any my systems with SSDs), open command prompt or powershell with admin rights and disable the feature fully by typing `powercfg -hibernate off` and pressing enter.  This will properly disable hibernate and remove the hiberfil.sys file from C: that can sometimes take up 10's of GB's of storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is math.

1 GB = 1024 MB, to a computer.
1 MB = 1024 KB, to a computer.

Therefore, do the math.  386 GB * 1024 (MB in 1 GB) = 395,000 MB (or so)

Comment: omg...cant't believe I forgot there are actually 1024MB in 1GB. That was so stupid....Thanks for reminding me :)